# Do vacuum bubbles lead to radiative EM field?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, virtual-particles

Imagine that a heavy particle $P$, moving with a uniform velocity, emits a photon $\gamma_1$ which is absorbed by a virtual electron in a vacuum bubble. As $P$ was not accelerating the photon $\gamma_1$ is an excitation of a purely "static" EM field ($1/r^2$) which accelerates the virtual electron. However the accelerating virtual electron then emits a photon $\gamma_2$ which is an excitation of an EM field with both "static" ($1/r^2$) and "radiative" ($1/r$) components.

Thus does the presence of vacuum bubbles lead to a radiative component to the otherwise purely static EM field emitted by a uniformly moving charged particle?

[image]

Comment: *" As $P$ was not accelerating the photon $γ_1$ is an excitation of a purely static EM field which accelerates the virtual electron. "* What is this supposed to mean? That's not how Feynman diagrams/quantum field theory work! There is no "acceleration" of lines in a Feynman diagram, and I have no idea what "an excitation of a purely static EM field" is supposed to mean, either.

Answer (score 0):

A moving charge creates a time-dependent EMF, not a static one. But it is still a "near" field, not radiated one. This field is supposed to get into the equations of motion of another charge as an "external field"; no other meaning is possible.
Your picture describes scattering of a real electron from the P-particle.